# How to upload a local text file to a textarea (inside the webpage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a novice programmer, and need some help figuring out how to upload a local text file to a textarea inside a website I'm building. I am very fluent in HTML/CSS, I have a decent knowledge of Javascript/JQuery, and I am just learning PHP. Any help you can give I would greatly appreciate. I have an input with type="file" and name="file" and I have a textarea with a class of ".textbox", and I have a button that runs the function "Upload()" Here is the javascript for my site.

```
var localfile = $("input[name=textfile]").val();

function Upload(){
  $(".textbox").append(file);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: correction the name of the input is "textfile"

Comment: "Upload"? Do you mean download?

Comment: I would probably do this on the back-end (PHP), because it requires the browser to support the HTML5 File API if you do it on the front-end. Long-story-short, you could have the file uploaded via the form, then have the form handler parse it and then display the file contents within the view. Check this out for some very basic file-handling examples: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php

Comment: If I got it right, you want user to pick a file and it gets automatically fed to the textarea (presumably, so that user doesn't have to open it in editor and copy/paste it, but still see and/or edit it). If this is the case, Flash might be a better approach, as it could do this locally, without talking to the server. JavaScript, to the best of my knowledge, would need PHP's (read: *server's*) help.

Comment: +1 on Matthew Blancarte. You need to read up on uploading a file to a variable and populating an element with variables.

Comment: Theoretical -1 to using Flash: totally inappropriate solution.

Comment: File API + server-side backup for IE

Comment: I am trying to make the website have a button that says "choose file" and it opens your up your documents (I have this so far) but I want the text file that is chosen to be displayed inside the textarea on the webpage. So my guess is that it would be uploaded to the site but I could be wrong. (I don't know if that helps at all)

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte So even though all browsers except IE9/8 support the File API, you're still going to make them all upload the file? #FAIL

Comment: @VedranŠego Yes thats what I am trying to do. can this only be accomplished through PHP?

Comment: @user2503334 as myself and other users have suggested so far, research a PHP solution. Stack overflow is here to help you when you run into problems, not write the code for you. Have a go at using/implementing PHP and consider asking a new question if you need further help.

Comment: @redditor I didn't know about File API until reading it here.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help I'll definitely have to learn more PHP (I'm just getting started on it) do you guys recommend any online courses/resources for learning PHP? I'm currently using http://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: @user2503334 PHP solution means upload to server and send back to user, which is quite a bit of unnecessary network traffic. This File API of HTML5 seems like a better solution, maybe combined with PHP for the browsers that don't support it. However, I just found out about it myself, so I cannot tell you how to do it. [Here](http://html5demos.com/file-api) is an interesting example that does with an image what you want with a text.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I was just making that suggestion based on the fact that OP doesn't seem to have a solid grasp on what JS can do with files. #YouAreAJerkBro

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Excuse me, but when a significantly inferior solution is used just because some older versions of one single browser don't support some APIs, then that's called a fail. It's backward and senseless. I'm not trying to be a jerk. The File API can handle this in about 5 lines of code. Surely OP should be able to grasp this small amount of JS code.

Answer (score 3):

Modern browsers implementing FileReader can do this. To test your browser check if window.FileReader is defined.

Here is some code I wrote a few days ago to do just this. In my case I simply drag a file onto the HTML element which is here referenced as panel.in1 but you can also use  (see the reference below).

```
if (window.FileReader) {
  function dragEvent (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation (); 
    ev.preventDefault ();
    if (ev.type == 'drop') {
      var reader = new FileReader ();
      reader.onloadend = function (ev) { panel.in1.value += this.result; };
      reader.readAsText (ev.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    }  
  }

  panel.in1.addEventListener ('dragenter', dragEvent, false);
  panel.in1.addEventListener ('dragover', dragEvent, false);
  panel.in1.addEventListener ('drop', dragEvent, false);
}
```

It is the reader.onloadend function which gets the text of the file which you recover in the event handler as this.result.

I got most of the mechanism on how to do this from MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

This code shows the basics of reading the file, the file itself is dragged into the text area, a nicer interface, I think, than having to go through the select file mechanisms, but those work equally well to select the file to read.

This is my answer to the similar question : [Get text file content using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922945/get-text-file-content-using-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be good to

upload the file using iframe which gives you a ajax like user experience is what Gmail doing,

and then read the contents of the file using php

then send the contents back through ajax then append to textarea using js.

Does this makes sense?

Comment: This is not what gmail is doing.

Comment: I am sorry if you don't know. I've seen Gmail used the iframe to upload files since ajax does not support multipart/form-data to give the user a dynamic ajax experience. Not sure about the current gmail version. Not using anymore..

Comment: Ajax does support multipart/form-data.  Perhaps you should take some time to update your knowledge before posting anymore answers on this topic.

Comment: Really thanks. This is what I've read in Internet. I do not have a legend like you to teach me. I tried to help. And I won't do that again in this site ;)